# Declaring my int array in C

Tags: c, arrays, static, int, constants

I want to initialize an int array with constant values, with all the 2^n values from 2^0 to 2^31 and I want to know which method below is right and if it gives the result I want and if there are easier or shorter methods to initialize it.

```
static const char     two_n[32];

two_n[32] = {1, 2 ,4 ,8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096,
               8192, 16384, 32768, 65535, 131070, 262140, 524280, 1048560,
               2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728,
               268435456, 536870912, 1073741824, 2147483648};
```

or

```
static const char     *two_n[32];

two_n[32] = {1, 2 ,4 ,8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096,
               8192, 16384, 32768, 65535, 131070, 262140, 524280, 1048560,
               2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728,
               268435456, 536870912, 1073741824, 2147483648};
```

or

```
static const int     two_n[32];

two_n[32] = {1, 2 ,4 ,8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096,
               8192, 16384, 32768, 65535, 131070, 262140, 524280, 1048560,
               2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728,
               268435456, 536870912, 1073741824, 2147483648};
```

Comment: None of these will work. Did you just try the code and see the results? You need to review your understanding of arrays. Try something simpler.

Comment: 65535 is wrong along with several more after that. You'd be better off filling the array with a simple `for` loop when the program starts. Or you could use hexadecimal notation for the constants, since the hexadecimal values follow a nice obvious pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm in an it school where using the for loops is forbidden in first year, and I can't use hexadecimal because I need to do a program that sorts numbers using Radix, and I am converting numbers to binary base then sorting using ascending binary order.

Comment: the values for the powers of 2 are given by: static const int two_n[32] = { 1<<0, 1<<2, 1<<3, 1<<4,..... 1<<31 };`

Comment: Note: after a `const` array is declared, it cannot be assigned to. (otherwise it would not be `const`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the above because both the types of the arrays and the initializers are incorrect. Use `uint32_t` or `unsigned long` as these are guaranteed to be at least 32-bit wide and able to hold the value of 2<sup>31</sup>, which might be beyond the range of `int`:

```
static const unsigned long two_n[32] = {
    1UL <<  0, 1UL <<  1, 1UL <<  2, 1UL <<  3,
    1UL <<  4, 1UL <<  5, 1UL <<  6, 1UL <<  7,
    1UL <<  8, 1UL <<  9, 1UL << 10, 1UL << 11,
    1UL << 12, 1UL << 13, 1UL << 14, 1UL << 15,
    1UL << 16, 1UL << 17, 1UL << 18, 1UL << 19,
    1UL << 20, 1UL << 21, 1UL << 22, 1UL << 23,
    1UL << 24, 1UL << 25, 1UL << 26, 1UL << 27,
    1UL << 28, 1UL << 29, 1UL << 30, 1UL << 31
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll use long type and not unsigned because I'll also need negative values.

Comment: @MohammedBRAHMI: If `long` type is 32-bit wide, it cannot hold 2^31. You would need `long long` which is guaranteed to hold at least up to `2^63-1`